# lassen / hinterlassen / überlassen / zurücklassen usw

Tags: verb

Die Frage entstand aus der Situation, dass meine Schwester mich darum gebeten hatte, ihr einen Zug von meinem Getränk zu *lassen* (?). Und dann haben wir nachgedacht, welches Wort für diese Situation gepasst hätte, und was der Unterschied zwischen den Variationen von -lassen ist.

Danke im Voraus!

Comment: Was sagt denn das Wörterbuch zu den Begriffen? Soviel Eigeninitiative erwarten wir eigentlich hier, und dann kann man, wenn trotzdem Fragen offen bleiben, darstellen, was unklar geblieben ist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was deine Schwester meinte ist, einen Rest zu lassen oder zu übergeben:

> **Lass** mir doch bitte etwas zu trinken **über**.

Das ist das Verb *überlassen* mit trennbarer Vorsilbe.

Außerdem gibt es noch das Verb *überlassen* mit nicht trennbarer Vorsilbe.

> **Überlass** mir doch bitte etwas zu trinken.

Der Unterschied ist, dass das nicht trennbare Verb ganz generell *schenken* meint, nicht einen Rest zu lassen oder zu übergeben. Hier wird also eher um eine ganze Flasche oder gar mehr gebeten.

---

*Zurücklassen* meint, etwas mehr oder weniger absichtlich irgendwo zu vergessen.

> **Lass** mich bitte nicht **zurück**.

*Hinterlassen* meint dasselbe, ist aber nicht auf Personen anwendbar.

> **Lassen** Sie bitte keinen Müll im Park **zurück**.
>
> **Hinterlassen** Sie bitte keinen Müll im Park.

Die einzige Ausnahme sind Verstorbene, die ihre Kinder hinterlassen.

> Sie **hinterlässt** zwei Söhne.

Comment: "lass mir etwas über" würde ich dem Gefühl nach dem süddeutschen Sprachraum zuordnen - für mich als Berliner ist "lass mir etwas übrig die gewohnte Formulierung. Falls es nicht explizit um den Rest geht, sondern einen Schluck zwischendurch, könnte man auch "gib mir bitte etwas ab" sagen

Comment: Nee, sagt man hier im Bereich Braunschweig/Harz auch. *Lass mir was über.* *Lass es einfach über.*